# cocos2d duplicating sprites bug

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, sprite

i have an app using cocos2d, 
Im moving some sprites and having animations when touched, it works fine until i load another view and come back again,
then when I move the sprites some random sprite will get duplicated when moved,

Please note the button that goes to the other view,

> sketchButtonTapped

Here some of the code,

```
 enum {  
easySprite =   0x0000000a,
mediumSprite = 0x0000000b,
hardSprite =   0x0000000c,
backButton =   0x0000000d,
magneticSprite = 0x0000000e,
magneticSprite2 = 0x0000000f
 };

@implementation HelloWorldLayer
@synthesize objetosDicto = _objetosDicto;
@synthesize bgMainScene = _bgMainScene;

+(CCScene *) scene
{
CCScene *scene = [CCScene node];

HelloWorldLayer *layer = [HelloWorldLayer node];

[scene addChild: layer];

return scene;
 }
-(id) init
{

if( (self=[super init])) {

    self.objetosDicto = [[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init] autorelease];


    self.bgMainScene = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"bgnd.png"];//Background

    self.bgMainScene.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0, 0);
    [self addChild:self.bgMainScene];

    isTouchEnabled_ = YES;

    CCMenuItem *starMenuItem = [CCMenuItemImage 
                                itemFromNormalImage:@"boton1.png" selectedImage:@"boton1Selected.png" 
                                target:self selector:@selector(starButtonTapped:)];

    starMenuItem.position = ccp(49, 299);
    CCMenu *starMenu = [CCMenu menuWithItems:starMenuItem, nil];
    starMenu.position = CGPointZero;
    [self addChild:starMenu];

    //secondo boton
    CCMenuItem *sketchV = [CCMenuItemImage itemFromNormalImage:@"sketchBoton.png" selectedImage:@"sketchBoton.png" target:self selector:@selector(sketchButtonTapped:)];

    sketchV.position = ccp(457, 160);
    CCMenu *sketchMenu = [CCMenu menuWithItems:sketchV, nil];
    sketchMenu.position = CGPointZero;
    [self addChild:sketchMenu];




    //first sprite
    TSprite *ez = [TSprite spriteWithFile:@"butonA.png"]; //lets create a TSprite, named EZ, and the file is Easy.png.
    [ez SetCanTrack:YES];//The sprite can be tracked.

    [self addChild: ez z:2 tag:easySprite]; //lets add a tag to the sprite, in order to identify it later RED
    ez.position = ccp(290,300);//position of the sprite
    [TSprite track:ez];//and lets add this sprite to the tracked array.


    //second sprite
    TSprite *med = [TSprite spriteWithFile:@"butonB.png"]; //blue
    [med SetCanTrack:YES];
    [self addChild: med z:1 tag:mediumSprite];
    med.position=ccp(299,230);
    [TSprite track:med];

    [self.objetosDicto setObject:@"299"forKey:@"hardX"]; //poner a salvar en finish toches??
    [self.objetosDicto setObject:@"160" forKey:@"hardY"]; //poner a salvar en finish toches?? 79

    //third sprite
    TSprite *har = [TSprite spriteWithFile:@"butonC.png"]; //GREEN
    [har SetCanTrack:YES];
    [self addChild: har z:3 tag:hardSprite];
    [har setPosition:ccp(299,160)];
    [TSprite track:har];

    //magnetic sprite
    TSprite *mag = [TSprite spriteWithFile:@"magnetic.png"];
    [mag SetCanTrack:YES]; //usar no! para ver que pasa!
    [self addChild:mag z:1 tag:magneticSprite];
    [mag setPosition:ccp(299, 180)];
    [TSprite track:mag];

    TSprite *mag2 = [TSprite spriteWithFile:@"magnetic.png"];
    [mag2 SetCanTrack:YES]; //usar no! para ver que pasa!
    [self addChild:mag2 z:1 tag:magneticSprite2];
    [mag2 setPosition:ccp(299, 140)];
    [TSprite track:mag2];


    [self getChildByTag:magneticSprite].visible = NO; //ojo, para aparece desaparece!
    [self getChildByTag:magneticSprite2].visible = NO; //ojo, para aparece desaparece!


}
return self;
 }


- (void)sketchButtonTapped:(id)sender {
NSLog(@"hundio");
CCTransitionRotoZoom *transition = [CCTransitionSlideInR transitionWithDuration:1.0 scene:  [SketchViewController scene]];


// Tell the director to run the transition

[[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:transition];

[tablaMenuBloq setHidden:YES];
}//sketchButtonTapped

 - (void)registerWithTouchDispatcher {
 [[CCTouchDispatcher sharedDispatcher] addTargetedDelegate:self priority:0 swallowsTouches:YES];
 } 


-(BOOL) ccTouchBegan:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{

 CGPoint location = [self convertTouchToNodeSpace:touch];

NSLog(@"locacion %f %f",location.x, location.y);


if([TSprite SomethingWasTouched:location]){     
    NSArray * mySprites = [TSprite allMySprites];
    NSUInteger i, count = [mySprites count];

    for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        TSprite * obj = (TSprite *)[mySprites objectAtIndex:i];

        if (CGRectContainsPoint([obj rect], location) && [obj GetCanTrack]) { 
             [obj setPosition :ccp(location.x,location.y)];//position of the spritesssss
             [self getChildByTag:magneticSprite]

            if([obj tag] == easySprite){



            }


        }
    }
}


    return TRUE;
 }
 -(void)ccTouchMoved:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event { 


CGPoint location = [self convertTouchToNodeSpace:touch];

 if([TSprite SomethingWasTouched:location]){        
    NSArray * mySprites = [TSprite allMySprites];
    NSUInteger i, count = [mySprites count];

    for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        TSprite * obj = (TSprite *)[mySprites objectAtIndex:i];

        if (CGRectContainsPoint([obj rect], location) && [obj GetCanTrack]) { 
            // code here is only executed if obj has been touched

            [obj setPosition :ccp(location.x,location.y)];//position of the spritesssss


            [self reorderChild:obj z:3]; //send layer to z front!!


            int s = [[self.objetosDicto objectForKey:@"hardY"]intValue];

            if ((location.y) < s+50) //79

            {
                [self getChildByTag:magneticSprite].visible = YES; //ojo, para aparece desaparece!
                [self getChildByTag:magneticSprite2].visible = NO; //ojo, para aparece desaparece!


                if ((location.y) < s-20)
                {
                    [self getChildByTag:magneticSprite].visible = NO; //ojo, para aparece desaparece!

                    [self getChildByTag:magneticSprite2].visible = YES; //ojo, para aparece desaparece!

                }



            }

            if ((location.y) > s+50) //79
            {
                [self getChildByTag:magneticSprite].visible = NO; //ojo, para aparece desaparece!

            }
            if ((location.y) < s-65) //79
            {
                [self getChildByTag:magneticSprite2].visible = NO; //ojo, para aparece desaparece!

            }


        }


                 }
}



 }

 -(void)ccTouchEnded:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {



CGPoint location = [self convertTouchToNodeSpace:touch];


if([TSprite SomethingWasTouched:location]){     
    NSArray * mySprites = [TSprite allMySprites];
    NSUInteger i, count = [mySprites count];

    for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        TSprite * obj = (TSprite *)[mySprites objectAtIndex:i];

        if (CGRectContainsPoint([obj rect], location) && [obj GetCanTrack]) { 
            // code here is only executed if obj has been touched


            [ obj runAction:[CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:0.3 position:ccp(299, 190)]];


            if([obj tag] == easySprite){



            }


        }
    }
}


 }

  - (void) dealloc
 {

[_bgMainScene release];
[_objetosDicto release];

[super dealloc];
}
 @end
```

Im also using a  TSSprite class, to keep track of the sprites, 
but dont think   that will make for the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Out of the blue I would say your app has a memory management issue. Since you're changing views (CCScenes I suppose) and the duplication only happens after that, the original scene and its children were probably not fully deallocated and are now shown again, or some of its sprites somehow make its way into the new scene.

One of the things that leads me to make this assumption is this line:

```
self.objetosDicto = [[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init] autorelease];
```

I presume the objectosDicto property is set to retain, otherwise you would experience crashes. That makes the autorelease completely superfluous. Which means you haven't fully embraced how Objective-C memory management works. [QED](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q.E.D.), sort of.

There's one simple test that you can do, which is to set a breakpoint in the HelloWorldLayer dealloc method. If the app doesn't break there when switching views, you're leaking the entire layer. If it does, you should try the same for the sprites which are duplicated and make sure that they too are all deallocated properly.

Comment: hi, thanks, thats right i have much to learn, after deallocating the sprites is working fine; one question please, why will the retain property be superflous with the autorelease?, thanks again